# Prevent collision on multiple database calls in Web API

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, rest, asp.net-web-api

I have a table of random unique number that they served as account Id for a user.

This scenario will use in Register method of Web API to get first unique Number and attached it into a user and after a successful creation, the fetched unique Number will be removed from database:

```
        public async Task<ActionResult> Register([FromBody] RegisterDto model)
    {

        //get the first unique number from the database
        var UniqueNumber = _context.UniqueNumbers.First();


        var user = new User
        {
            UserName = model.Email,
            Email = model.Email,
            PhoneNumber = model.PhoneNumber,
            FirstName = model.FirstName,
            LastName = model.LastName,
            UserProfile = new UserProfile()
            {
                AccountNumber = UniqueNumber.Number,
            },
        };

        //creating user
        var createResult = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
        if (!createResult.Succeeded) return BadRequest(new { isSucceeded = createResult.Succeeded, errors = createResult.Errors });

        //Delete the fetched UniqueId from the database
        _context.UniqueNumbers.Remove(UniqueNumber);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        return Ok(new
        {
            isSucceeded = true
        });
    }
```

My question is how do I prevent collision in multiple calls on API since it may return same unique number for multiple calls?

Comment: What database?  What version of EF? There's not a generic way to do this.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I'm using EF Core 2.1 and MSSQL, I Was thinking about use Transaction Scope but I'm not sure how this works...

Comment: Why even go to a table for this?  Could you just use a guide type and generate it using a combguid from you c# code.

Comment: @Fran Well I really need this Id to be a integer value and 10 digits only. (business logic), So no I can't use a GUID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On EF Core and Microsoft SQL Server you should simply use a SEQUENCE object to generate your keys.  See [Sequences - EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/sequences)

If really, really want to proceed with your original design you could use FromSql to run a [DELETE … OUTPUT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), something like:

```
var UniqueNumber = _context.UniqueNumbers.FromSql("delete top (1) from UniqueNumbers output deleted.*").Single();
```

Comment: Well the Sequences does not meet my requirement as I said (Not Randomly Generated.), So I think I should stick to my design.
However this command will do my work perfectly I think, Many thanks!